# ¿Cómo crear tablas relacionales en Symfony con atributos?

Tags: base-de-datos, symfony, relaciones

soy nuevo en Symfony, y estoy intentando hacer relaciones usando las entidades de Symfony, mas o menos esto es lo que quiero crear:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el otro problema que tengo son el nombre de las relaciones que no me deja elegirlas en la BD siempre crea un user_producto y eso me crea conflictos, solo quiero saber si se puede hacer con entidades o tengo que hacerlo a pelo en otra parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es correcto, deberas de realizarlo por entidades, de hecho es mucho mas sencillo, puedes ver la documentacion de esto en este [link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping), como hacer la asociación a mano o puedes tomar este curso de symfonycast donde te enseñan como hacerlo [link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-doctrine/create-entity)